# How can I solve the Marquee stumble problem?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Laravel + Vue.js. I shoot the announcements through the API. But when I write with my hand, the marquee works fine. It slips in a continuous loop. But when I want to print the value that comes with vue.js, the text doesn't shift when it reaches the end. Hanging. Shaking.

```
$('.marquee').marquee({
    //speed in milliseconds of the marquee
    duration: 8000,
    //gap in pixels between the tickers
    gap: 0,
    //time in milliseconds before the marquee will start animating
    delayBeforeStart: 0,
    //'left' or 'right'
    direction: 'left',
    //true or false - should the marquee be duplicated to show an effect of continues flow
    duplicated: true
});
```

**Vue.js Code**

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            announcements: ""
        }
    },

    created() {
        this.getAnnouncements();
    },

    methods: {
        getAnnouncements() {
            axios.get('/get-announcements')
                .then((response) => {
                    this.announcements = response.data;
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                })
        }
    },

    mounted() {
        setInterval(() => {
            this.getAnnouncements();
        }, 10000);
    },

    watch: {
        announcements(val) {
            this.announcements = val
        }
    }
}
```

**Working;**

[image]

```
<div id="tv-announcement" class="marquee">
    Lorem ipsum test.Lorem ipsum test.Lorem ipsum test.Lorem ipsum test. 
</div>
```

**Not working;**

[image]

```
<div id="tv-announcement" class="marquee">
    {{ announcements }}
</div>
```

Why is this happening? It's ridiculous.

Comment: Try putting same content to first and second example. I see that first one also jumps, but maybe content is different and makes it look good?

Comment: Please share your vue code as well.

Comment: No, it works correctly. Only gif seconds error. @Justinas

Comment: I added the vue.js code. @Tuna

Answer (score -1):

Initialize your marquee after you get the data from AJAX request. And you do not need to watch `announcements` as it is already a reactive property.

Comment: Can you make sample editing? It seems to be useless.